# BotService Slack channel connection returns Slack API Error to message sent

Tags: botframework, slack, azure-bot-service

After connecting Slack to Azure Bot Service following instruction from the link, Azure does not bypass the message to bot server. Sreenshots are from `Issue` which appears by clicking on issue button next to the channel. Issue appears every time I send message from Slack.

Anyone encountered similar case?
Error message is little unkind...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-slack?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=abs

BTW, test chat on portal is working as expected.

[image: slack error screen shot]

Comment: What do you mean "Azure does not bypass the message to the bot server"? Do you mean the message sent by the user in Slack is never received by the bot? And, are those the only instances of the error showing or has it come up more than those two times? Lastly, have you double checked every step was completed correctly with the correct values?

Comment: Thanks for the comment!
Updating all tokens (client id, secret, etc. )  made bot working! (This was my forth or fifth time updating... But it seems to me my mistake on registering tokens. 
Sorry for taking your time.


> Do you mean the message sent by the user in Slack is never received by the bot?
MS teams hasn't send message to bot.
> And, are those the only instances of the error showing or has it come up more than those two times?
yes, it showed multipletimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triple checking my tokens, it fixed error. So it seems to be my mistake on setting token...

When error message spotted out credential error, it would have made my life easier...